# Search and Replace - How do you change a specific string across syntactically similar files?

Tags: search, replace, macro, multiple-files

I'm attempting to write a Vim macro that will allow me to replace a single variable of a single service across multiple Icinga configuration files. Services are syntactically very similar so I constructed a multi-tier search before replacing the variable.

Writing the Macro:

```
qd
/SERVICE_2
/max_check_attempts
:s/5/10/g
q
```

Running the Macro:

```
vim config-file-*.cfg 
:argdo @d 
:wqall
```

Executing this macro however results in only a single file being written, the first one in the args list, whereas I want to make the change to multiple config files (config-file-1.cfg, config-file-2.cfg, etc.). Where am I going wrong? and how do I resolve this issue?

### Further Details

Vim Register for @d:

```
"d   /SERVICE_2^M/max_check_attempts^M:s/5/10g<80>kb/g^M
```

Args of vim config-file-*.cfg:

```
[config-file-10.cfg] config-file-1.cfg config-file-2.cfg config-file-3.cfg confi
g-file-4.cfg config-file-5.cfg config-file-6.cfg config-file-7.cfg config-file-8
.cfg config-file-9.cfg
```

Example contents of a config file:

```
define service{
        use                             generic-service 
        host_name                       host1
        service_description             SERVICE_1
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    mainperiod
        max_check_attempts              5
        normal_check_interval           4
        retry_check_interval            30
        contact_groups                  mycontacts
        notification_interval           15
        notification_period             mainperiod
        notification_options            w,u,c,r
        check_command                   check_service_1
}

define service{
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       host1
        service_description             SERVICE_2
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    mainperiod
        max_check_attempts              5
        normal_check_interval           13
        retry_check_interval            7
        contact_groups                  mycontacts
        notification_interval           15
        notification_period             mainperiod
        notification_options            w,u,c,r
        check_command                   check_service_2
}

define service{
        use                             generic-service    
        host_name                       host1
        service_description             SERVICE_3
        is_volatile                     0
        check_period                    mainperiod
        max_check_attempts              5
        normal_check_interval           7
        retry_check_interval            9
        contact_groups                  mycontacts
        notification_interval           15
        notification_period             mainperiod
        notification_options            w,u,c,r
        check_command                   check_service_3
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered as well as any quality-of-life and best practices suggestions.

Comment: Not sure why saves aren't happening but I'd consider doing away with the macro and just putting the command on the argdo line: `:argdo /SERVICE_2/;/max_check_attempts/ s/5/10/g`. The `/foo/;/bar/` notation at the start means "go to first occurrence of foo and then the first occurrence of bar following foo"...I think that's what you want to do.

Comment: A matter of personal taste is the use of macros here. You could also use a single substitute command: `%s/\(SERVICE_2\_.\{-}max_check_attempts\s*\)\d*/\110/`. It uses `\_.` to match everything including linebreaks, grouping into an atom `\( \)` and `\{-}` the non-greedy version of `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:argdo @d` doesn’t act like executing `@d` in every buffer in the arg list: it instead runs `:@d` in each buffer. It doesn’t execute the contents of the d register as a *macro*: it executes them as an *Ex command*. See `:help argdo` and `:help :@`.

Try `:argdo norm!@d` instead.